# qt : show mouse position like tooltip

Tags: qt, mouse-cursor, qcursor

As I write on title, I hope to show mouse position like tooltip. To do that, I think that I have to override QCursor, right?

But I don't know the details of QCursor and how to make a new cursorShape.

Is there any example like this?

Comment: What do you really want to do? Is it showing to the user where his mouse is or just changing the mouse cursor to show a waiting wheel for example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you want a coordinate readout as you move the cursor (like in many graphics or CAD applications), you really **do not** want to override `QCursor`.

The most efficient approach depends on what widget will be providing the coordinates, but in most cases the simplest way will be to `setMouseTracking(true)` for the widget, and override it's `mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)` to display a `QToolTip` like so:

```
void MyWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    QToolTip::showText(event->globalPos(),
                       //  In most scenarios you will have to change these for
                       //  the coordinate system you are working in.
                       QString::number( event->pos().x() ) + ", " +
                       QString::number( event->pos().y() ),
                       this, rect() );
    QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(event);  // Or whatever the base class is.
}
```

Normally you would not 'force' a tooltip like this; you would use `QWidget::setToolTip(const QString&)` or capture tooltip events in `QWidget::event(QEvent*)`.  But normal `QToolTip`s only appear after short delay, but you want them updated continuously.

I should state that I haven't tried this, but this is the way I would do it.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your advise.
While I wait for a reply, I find a similar way. I use QLineEdit instead of QToolTip. With QLineEdit, I can let the "custom toolTip" follow the cursor.