# How to display a label near the mouse cursor in VTK

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I am working on a displaying a small label near the cursor. So that I can show some information to the user over the parts of image. I have search on the web for many times. But it seems that there is no proper solution.

My program is built using vtk and qt. I can build a more user-friendly UI once I can do this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Try with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417636/qt-show-mouse-position-like-tooltip

Comment: google for qt tooltips

Comment: I think I have a problem using qt. Is it possible to use vtk?

Comment: @ManLokHui: Since my comment helped you, I've converted it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [vtkTextActor](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/c2_vtk_e_8.html#c2_vtk_e_vtkTextActor)?